# Local variable initialized inside 'if' is still available after that 'if' in C#

Tags: c#, if-statement, scope

Have not found an answer to this question yet (proboply because I am looking wrong for it). I was just wondering following. Why is it not possible to have this code:

```cs
if (obj is string str) {
    // do stuff
}
if (obj is string str) {
    // do stuff
}
```

This would throw following error: *Error    CS0128  A local variable or function named 'str' is already defined in this scope*

I know I could use this instead:

```cs
{
    if (obj is string str) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
{
    if (obj is string str) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

But it has other disadvantages, the biggest beeing more lines of code for me.

I would guess its because the compiler actually converts the code (the upper of the two) to following:

```cs
string str = obj as string;
if (str != null) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Or something simillar.

If this is the case I wonder why and if there may already be a better way than writing:

```cs
if (obj is string str1) {
    // do stuff
}
if (obj is string str2) {
    // do stuff
}
if (obj is string str3) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Hope someone can tell me what the problems in C# Logic are and a way to deal with it. If a Question like this already exists please link it I really could not find one.

**Edit:** Because the usecase of this was asked. First of I want to know the logic behind that in **general** but secondly I have an usecase for this right now which will not be possible to hanndle differently because of some reasons.

It would be useful in a case where I have e.g. different data that is passed and I do the type-specific operation1 then something that both need and then another operation that is type-specific.

Comment: It's not clear to me why you want to repeatedly test the same condition or repeatedly declare the same variable in the first place.  The code shown implies that you probably want to re-structure your logic anyway.

Comment: I'm assuming `obj` is actualy `obj1`, `obj2`, `obj3`... And you are not testing the some condition multiple times?

Comment: For additional information, [here are the design notes about the scope for pattern variables](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/12939)

Comment: @David I specified the answer to your questions directly in my question as an edit :D

Comment: @Joas both could be the case here but more like beeing a question about this behaviour in general

Comment: `if (obj is string) {
    string str = obj as string;
}` then you can repeat the if-statement as many times as you want

Comment: @MarcoBeninca makes sense but is quiet inconviniet to use sadly.

Comment: @MatthewWatson did not read through all yet cause of time issues but quiet interessting. Thank you very much.

Comment: @AtLeastVision it's just a work around to avoid `str1 str2` and keep the code clean

Comment: @MarcoBeninca Yep I know. Appreciated :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is, why is the error: *"Error CS0128 A local variable or function named 'str' is already defined in this scope"* .

The answer is, The code `if (obj is string str1)` is syntactic sugar for declaring a variable and assigning it.

I used [sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQAwAIpwHQBECWAhgOYB2A9gM4Au+AxpQNzLJQDMmM6AwusgN7J0wzBygAWdAFkAFAEo+SEekFLlI8gCMAVgFM61dFu3oAvOgBEAFV01McVBeZr1i18PwAzdDOPp8lPYYNABOcHJC7qru6lgAnDIAJBb8xgC+/oGEQRZyzjFpkcKFSGlAA=) for this:

```
public class C 
{
    public void M() 
    {
        object obj = "Test string";
        
        if (obj is string str1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{obj} is a string");
        }
    }
}
```

Is compiled to:

```
public class C
{
    public void M()
    {
        object obj = "Test string";
        string text = obj as string;
        if (text != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} is a string", obj));
        }
    }
}
```

So the obj variable is NOT declared in the inner scope but in the outer scope.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. So its actually just as I though it is. Quiet sad to be honest but makes sense. Thank you very much. Any Idea if there are better solutions than which I provided in my Question?

Comment: @AtLeastVision That's just an implementation detail. During development of this feature, there were versions where the scope WAS restricted. For the lowdown on why the language itself was designed this way, see the link I posted in a comment to your question.

Comment: Sometimes I have the same struggles. For example, using the switch statement. All cases of a switch statement share the same scope.

Comment: Either use meaningful variable names. If it's hard to give it a meaningful name, you should probably review the code you've written. It might be a sign of code smell or the need of refactoring.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Would have appreciated the other implementation more tbh but it is what it is. Thank you very much.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Yep I know its super annoying tbh.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen I would use a meaningfull name its just that in both cases it would be the same name because it just makes sense. Its also less about having x variables with 1, 2, ..., x but that I have more variables that store something which is irrelevant. But I know multiple ways to handle this now. Thank you :D

Answer (score 1):

Just to suggest an alternative way to declare things to avoid the compile error:

You can declare the variable outside the conditions, and then use it like so:

```
string? str;

if ((str = obj as string) != null)
{
    // do stuff
}
if ((str = obj as string) != null)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

It's not a lot better, but you might prefer it.

Comment: DId not think about this I tried `if ((string str = obj as string) != null)` which obv did not work. Thanks alot.